# Is retrieving data from a redis instance slower than retreiving the same from Django's request.session dictionary?

Tags: django, redis

In a Python/Django application, is retrieving a value stored in redis slower than retrieving one stored in the `request.session` dictionary?

---

**Background:**
I have a Django app where I use DB-based sessions. I.e., instead of using `django.contrib.sessions`, I used this nifty little [3rd party library](https://github.com/Bouke/django-user-sessions).

I recently ran a benchmark whereby I saved a test value in a local redis instance via the [redis-py wrapper](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (i.e. `my_server.set('test','1')`). I saved the same test value in `request.session['test']`.

I then retrieved the test value from each, and compared the time taken. `request.session` out performed redis by a factor exceeding 2x in this scenario.

---

**Problem:**
The application is not distributed in any way, everything is shared and happens on the same machine - very vanilla set up.

The result appears counter-intuitive to me. Why? Because my sessions are DB based, and I thought redis would be faster than whatever Django has to offer. Clearly, I am wrong.

Can an expert explain what's actually going on here? Maybe the python wrapper on redis' core API is slowing things down?

---

In case you need more information, or are skeptical about how I ran the benchmark, please do ask.

P.s. I simply put the two competing ways in a for loop for 100K iterations and measured the time taken to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session is stored as a single blob, not as individual keys. It has almost certainly already been loaded and decoded by the time you get into your view, most likely by the auth middleware. Once it is loaded it is stored locally as a dictionary, which is all that your timing tests will measure.

Comment: Ah okay, so the comparison results aren't trustworthy in the sense that I'm not doing a like-for-like comparison here. Thanks!

Comment: Also, using sessions, the data only gets written back to the backing store (whether it's a database, Redis, flat files, whatever) at the end of the request.

Comment: @AKX: implication being?

Comment: That even writing into the session dict is (practically) as fast as writing to a regular in-memory dict within a single request.

Comment: @AKX: True, but my use-case also includes retrieval of said data.